# object doesnt support object IE 8

Tags: javascript, extjs, minimize

when i want to minimize a extjs window it is not working in IE8. All the other browsers are fine. The error i get is pointing to a line with this in it:

```
iframe.dom.hasOwnProperty
```

Is this something that is not working for IE8?

also there is

```
iframe.dom.contentWindow.parentLostFocus();
```

The error in IE is just saying: object doesn't support object. Not sure what the issue could be. Anyone an idea?

this is the focus

```
iframe = Ext.get('iframe_{0}'.sprintf(item.itemId));
if(!iframe.dom.hasOwnProperty('contentWindow')) {
  return;
}

if(iframe !== null && iframe.dom && iframe.dom.contentWindow && iframe.dom.contentWindow.parentGotFocus) {
  context.trace('calling parentGotFocus in iframe {0}'.sprintf(item.itemId));
  iframe.dom.contentWindow.parentGotFocus();
} else {
  context.trace('function parentGotFocus not found in iframe {0}'.sprintf(item.itemId));
}
},
```

Comment: what is `dom`? i've never heard of that property on an iframe element.

Comment: well maybe that is the issue then :P i update the question

Answer (score 6):

IE8 and less does not support `hasOwnProperty()` for DOM elements. If `iframe.dom` is DOM Node object, then IE8 throw an error *"Object does not support property or method"*. To avoid error try to replace:

```
iframe.dom.hasOwnProperty("property name");
```

with:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(iframe.dom,"property name");
```